# How to use process substitution when executing commands through a bash array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process-substitution

I have a simple bash script that looks like this, which adds two "printer" processes that print words in a loop to an array and executes them, storing their process IDs. I am trying to user process substitution to filter out a piece of text that gets printed, but I keep getting the error `grep: <(./usr/bin/printscript2.sh): No such file or directory`

The scripts for the printer processes are similar but printscript1 just has some different words, so I'll add the code for printscript2 below the parent process.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup array for the commands we wish to execute
procs_arr=()
procs_arr+=("/usr/bin/printscript1.sh")
procs_arr+=("grep -v FILTERMEPLEASEENDTHISMISERY <(/usr/bin/printscript2.sh)")

num_procs=${#procs_arr[@]}
echo "num_procs = $num_procs"


# Run the commands and store pids to an array
pids=()
for (( i=0; i<"$num_procs"; i++ )); do
    echo "cmd = ${procs_arr[$i]}"
    ${procs_arr[$i]} &
    pids+=("$!")
    echo "    pid = ${pids[$i]}"
done

while true; do
  sleep 1000
done

exit 0
```

```
!/bin/bash

sleep 3
while true; do
  sleep 5
  echo "parrot"
  sleep 5
  echo "FILTERMEPLEASEENDTHISMISERY"
  sleep 5
  echo "socks"
done
```

I executed the same command using process substitution locally in the shell (i.e. ran "grep -v FILTERMEPLEASEENDTHISMISERY <(/usr/bin/printscript2.sh)" in bash directly) and it worked as intended, meaning the string was filtered out from the console prints. I'm not sure if there's some special formatting I'm missing here. I also tried to use escape characters so putting a backslash '' in front of '<', '(', and ')' and got the same error `grep: \<\(/usr/bin/printscript2.sh\): No such file or directory`. Is this a function that is only supposed to be supported when directly done in a bash shell, or am I typing something incorrectly?

Comment: Code does not belong in variables. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Arrays are the appropriate tool for storing command lines, but `<()` is not a command-line element, it's syntax; use a function instead.

Comment: Bash syntax is not processed after expanding variables. You would have to use `eval "${procs_arr[$i]}"` to do what you want.

Comment: (Also, the process substitution _creates an extra process_, so you use `eval` to force it to work, your nprocs count is too low... and of course you have [all the risks of `eval`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Comment: ...one approach to consider: Define a function with `myproc() { grep -v FILTERMEPLEASEENDTHISMISERY <(/usr/bin/printscript2.sh); }`, and then use `procs_arr+=( "myproc" )`

Comment: ...actually, that you're attempting to run `${procs_arr[$i]}` makes BashFAQ #50 **exactly** on-point.